# How to expose your models to the app and to routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, orientdb, waterline

I am using [Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline) as my ORM together with Express. I am wondering what the best way is to expose my models so I can use them in my app. So far I have to call `req.app.models.model_name` which seems a bit complicated. This code example works but I'm just not so sure if this is good practice since I'm quite new to Node.js / Waterline and Express.

My folder structure is the one made by express generator with some modifications:

```
├── app.js
├── bin
│   └── www
├── models
│   ├── index.js
│   └── links.js
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── images
│   ├── javascripts
│   └── stylesheets
│       └── style.css
├── routes
│   ├── index.js
│   └── users.js
└── views
    ├── error.jade
    ├── index.jade
    └── layout.jade
```

This is how I use Waterline inside my models. I have an index.js to setup Waterline and it automatically loads any other models in the folder `./models`

```
// ./models/index.js

var orientAdapter = require('sails-orientdb');
var Waterline = require('waterline');

var orm = new Waterline();

var config = {
  // Setup Adapters
  // Creates named adapters that have have been required
  adapters: {
    'default': orientAdapter,
    orient: orientAdapter,
  },

  // Build Connections Config
  // Setup connections using the named adapter configs
  connections: {
    myLocalOrient: {
      adapter: 'orient',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 2424,
      user: 'root',
      password: 'password',
      database: 'database'
    }
  },

  defaults: {
    migrate: 'alter'
  }
};

// Include all files in ./models directory
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require("path");

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js");
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = require(path.join(__dirname, file));
    orm.loadCollection(model);
  });

module.exports = {waterline: orm, config: config};
```

An example model (`Link`):

```
// ./models/link.js

var Waterline = require('Waterline');
var orientAdapter = require('sails-orientdb');

var Link = Waterline.Collection.extend({
  identity: 'link',
  connection: 'myLocalOrient',

  attributes: {

    title: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    url: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    }
  }
});

module.exports = Link;
```

To hook it into my app I modified `./bin/www` which you use to start the app (`node ./bin/www`)

```
// ./bin/www


#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('v2:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
// START SERVER STARTUP WITH WATERLINE
var models = require('../models');

models.waterline.initialize(models.config, function(err, models) {
  if(err) throw err;
  //  console.log(models.collections);
  app.models = models.collections;
  app.connections = models.connections;

  // Start Server
  server.listen(port);
  server.on('error', onError);
  server.on('listening', onListening);
});

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

I can now use the models in my routes like so:

```
// ./routes/index.js    

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = require('../app');

// Index
router.get('/links', function(req, res, next) {
    req.app.models.link.find().limit(10).then(function(links) { 
        res.json(links); 
    });
});

// Create
router.post('/links', function(req, res, next) {
    var link = req.app.models.link.create(req.body)
    .then(function(link) {
        res.json(link);     
    })
    .catch(console.error);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Note the use of `req.app.models.link.find()...`.

I started to get worried about it when I tried to hook in [Passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) and created a file `./config/passport.js`. With my first implementation I got the error `ReferenceError: req is not defined` so I had to change it and pass the request object into my passport strategy. Like so:

```
// ./routes/index.js

// ...

// Login User
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password){
    return res.status(400).json({message: 'Please fill out all fields'});
  }

  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    if(user){
      return res.json({token: user.generateJWT()});
    } else {
      return res.status(401).json(info);
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

And my passport local strategy:

```
// ./config/passport.js

var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback : true
  },
  function(req, username, password, done) { 
    // check in orientdb if a user with username exists or not
    req.app.models.user.findOne({ 'username' :  username }, 
      function(err, user) {
        // In case of any error, return using the done method
        if (err) return done(err);
        // Username does not exist, log error & redirect back
        if (!user){
          console.log('User Not Found with username '+username);
          return done(null, false, { message: 'User Not Found with username '+username });                 
        }
        // User exists but wrong password, log the error 
        if (!user.verifyPassword(password)){
          console.log('Invalid Password');
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid Password'});
        }
        // User and password both match, return user from 
        // done method which will be treated like success
        return done(null, user);
      }
    );
}));
```

Maybe this is fine but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

**Question: Is this a good way to expose my Waterline models to my app? Or am I missing something?**

Comment: You already have a reference to `app`, there's no need to go to `req` to get it. Additionally, you could store a reference to `Link` at the top so that you're using it directly as `Link` instead of `app.models.link` without changing anything else.

Comment: @KevinB Well, not really. If I try to reference app directly in `./config/passport.js` I get the error `ReferenceError: app is not defined`. Same if I try to reference it at the top. Or what do you mean with "You already have a reference to app"?

Comment: `var app = require('../app');` in your route, it's already there.

Comment: `var app = require('../app'), user = app.models.user;` results in `Cannot read property 'user' of undefined` since the models are made available in `./bin/www`

Comment: i see. I don't have that problem because i ensure all of my models are defined before i begin defining my routes.

Comment: Is the object you get from app.models.Link the same one being exported from the link.js in models? If so, you might be able to just require that directly. `var Link = require('../models/link')`

Comment: I am pretty sure this is the problem. I am just following how the express generator sets up the app since I thought this should be a good way to do it. But having the server startup in `./bin/www` and the routing and application logic in `app.js` is confusing me when what is available and in which scope.

Comment: This is further reference on how Waterline works together with Express: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/master/example/express/express-example.js

Comment: yeah, i can't stand the generators, i like organize to my startup process a specific way. Get DB Connection, define models, add pre-middleware, define routes, add post-middleware, start listening for requests. each step waits for the previous to be complete. I build my models so they can be directly required by the route so i don't have to store them on app or req..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81013/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-ole-bjarnstroem).

Comment: Yes, you need to ensure the models are initialised before you use them. Using `app` to keep track of them looks like a good way of sharing the models across your application.